# How to get FileName from url

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have url like `http://xxx.xxx.xxx/mls/pmmls/12/-8/53/6/12-8536_2.jpg/t1349940727/100x100/`
and need to get only filename from url like "`12-8536_2.jpg"`

```
url format is dynamic. Filename with extension must be in url. but it filename with extension  may not be in last position of url
```

I have tried Path.GetFileName() but it give "".

is anyone know how extract filename for this type of url?

Comment: If you say that the filename may or may not contain an extension, then how would you differentiate a file name from the other string values? Humans must be able to tell the filename in order for them to write a program to do that for them.

Comment: What do you intend to do with URLs of the form http://example.com/xxx/image.jpg/yyy/index.html/zzz?

Comment: Maybe `t1349940727` is the filename not `12-8536_2.jpg` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

12-8536_2.jpg does not seem to be a file in that URL. In any case, if the "filename" in the URL will always be in .jpg, you can output the URL to a string (or *AS* a string) and Regex for it:

```
string filename = Regex.Match(URL,@"\/([A-Za-z0-9\-._~:?#\[\]@!$%&'()*+,;=]*).jpg").Groups[1].Value
```

EDIT: I'm thinking this is for a site with different preview sizes for a specific file. You can also specify the different possible extensions as follows (for example):

```
string filename = Regex.Match(URL,@"\/([A-Za-z0-9\-._~:?#\[\]@!$%&'()*+,;=]*)(.jpg|.JPG|.jpeg|.JPEG)").Groups[1].Value
```

Comment: The Regex above will miss that (forgot about percent codes) - Just put a % somewhere in the first parenthesis, inside the braces- e.g. beside the dollar sign like so @"\/([A-Za-z0-9\-._~:?#\[\]@!$%&'()*+,;=]*)(.jpg|.JPG|.jpeg|.JPEG)". I edited my answer above.

Answer (score 1):

There is no guarantee that any part of a URL maps to a file, so it does not make sense to try to get the *FileName* in a URL.

Answer (score 0):

If you *know* the filename will always be followed by two further segments (in your example, `t1349940727` and `100x100`), you could do

```
var input =
    "http://xxx.xxx.xxx/mls/pmmls/12/-8/53/6/12-8536_2.jpg/t1349940727/100x100/";
var uri = new Uri(input);
var fileName = uri.Segments[uri.Segments.Length - 3];
```

If you don't know that, then as others have said, there's no easy way to tell which part is the filename. You could try

```
var fileName = url.Segments.Last(seg => seg.Contains("."));
```

to get the last segment with a dot in.

Answer (score 0):

You should define a list of extensions, like .jpg, .png .gif (all files types you are expecting).

Convert your url to string (if it isnt already) and try to find the index of  the extension. You do now know the position of the file name and whether there is an file name. remove everything after the file name.

now find a "/" token, and remove the part before (and including) the "/" , repeat this untill you can no longer find "/" (for example with a while function).

more information on how to do this can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wtc81z6.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
static string getFileName(string url) {
    string[] arr = url.Split('/');
    return arr[arr.Length - 1];
}
```

Comment: explain this answer more